"The rmaining 3 parcels" Vs. "The rest 3 parcels"
If I need to get 9 parcels today, and so far I got 6. So:

During the day I'm supposed to get the remaining 3 parcels?

Vs.

During the day I'm supposed to get the rest 3 parcels?

One of the above, both of them, or non of them is natural / idiomatic to the English native speaker?
Intuitively, I go with the first option (remaning), but I am not sure if the other option is wrong.

As written, remaining is the right word. But you can also use rest if you change the syntax: During the day I'm supposed to get the rest of the parcels.

In more formal writing, careful writers often use words rather than figures for numbers smaller than (usually) 11, so would write the remaining three parcels or the rest of the three parcels.

Your intuition is correct. "remaining 3 parcels" is the way a native English speaker would say it.
"The rest 3" is just plain wrong and you would never hear it said.
However you could correctly say.

During the day I'm supposed to get the rest of the parcels.


As far as I understand, saying "the rest of the 3 parcels" implicates that I had 3 full parcels, but I got the majority of the stuff fromthese three parcels, but still I am waiting for the rest of those 3. While our case is a bit different. Isn't it?

@VirtuousLegend I would understand "The rest of the 3 parcels" to mean that you have already received some parcels (1 or 2) but not all 3 and you are now waiting for the remainder  of them (2 or 1) to make up the full delivery of 3. But at no time were you expecting more than 3.
